# Circular Queue Python

Tags: python, data-structures

I am trying to make a circular queue in Python so that when the last element in the array is reached to points back to the head. I am working on the enqueue method and I am having some issues. I am trying to have an array of size 4 and I am able to enqueue values up to the 4th spot, but when it executes the elif statement I receive this error.

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Node' and 'int'

Any thoughts?

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, item = None):
        self.item = [None] * 4
        self.next = None
        self.previous = None

class CircularQueue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
    def enqueue(self, x):
        newNode = Node(x)
        newNode.next = None
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = newNode
            self.tail = newNode
        elif self.length < 4:
            self.tail.next = newNode
            newNode.previous = self.tail
            self.tail = newNode
        else:
            self.tail = (self.tail + 1) % 4
        self.length += 1
    def dequeue(self):
        if self.count == 0:
            print ("The Queue is empty!")
        self.count -= 1
        return self.item.pop()
    def size(self):
        return self.length
```

Comment: Looks like a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is already a [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) in collections.

Comment: You are using both `self.count` and `self.length` instance variables. Be consistent.

Comment: I am trying to make my own ADT, not using an existing module.

Comment: Circular queues are usually implemented as a fixed-length array or as a linked list. In a fixed-length array method you do not need head and tail attributes in your node since you can access the next item by incrementing the index variable. In a linked list, you do not need to keep track of the length. Be consistent.

Comment: To echo @wim there is a deque object available - it has a couple of methods like `append` and `rotate` that might be very useful for implementing what you want.

Comment: What is the relevance of 4? why if `self.length < 4`?

Comment: What do you expect `(self.tail + 1)` to do, if not throw a TypeError?

Comment: @aestrivex to make the index wrap around to the beginning of the array. And the relevance of 4 is make it an array of size 4. How else would I declare its size?

Comment: You are using a hybrid of array & linked list implementation for deque? why not use a pure dynamic array or linked list implementation?

Comment: How would I make it a dynamic array?

Comment: By dynamic array, I mean a simple list of the nodes. The head & tail will be indices in the list. If an enqueue cannot happen because list is full, allocate new list with double size, copy everything over from the old list and use the new list. This will give amortized O(1) & worst case O(n) enqueue

Comment: You expect `self.tail + 1` to "make the index wrap around to the beginning of the array?" What does that mean? Your thinking about how to implement this data structure is very muddled, and you need to organize it.

Answer (score 19):

If you don't have to implement this yourself, you can use the standard library `deque`

```
from collections import deque

circular_queue = deque([1,2], maxlen=4)
circular_queue.append(3)
circular_queue.extend([4])

# at this point you have [1,2,3,4]
print(circular_queue.pop())  # [1,2,3] --> 4

# key step. effectively rotate the pointer
circular_queue.rotate(-1)  # negative to the left. positive to the right

# at this point you have [2,3,1]
print(circular_queue.pop())  # [2,3] --> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
self.tail + 1
```

but before, you initiated tail to be a Node:

```
self.tail = newNode
```

Thus the error.

Comment: Why does that matter? I want it to wrap around to the beginning once it has reached 4. That section of code should not even be executing once onto the else statement.

Comment: Well, your "old" `self.tail` is a node (since it was set to `newNode`), it is not some sort of index. Once 4 is reached, you have to link the tail to the head.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to point you in the right direction because it looks like you are trying to learn how to implement a circular queue and maybe learning to program at the same time.  The error message is trying to tell you the variable self.tail is an object and that it cannot be added to a number (integer).

The line of code:

```
self.tail = (self.tail + 1) % 4
```

is the issue causing the error.  However there are some core concepts which need to be understood before trying to fix that one line.  For instance you don't have to make an array in your Node object.  Self.item can be set to anything. and it seems it may be confusing the purpose of the circular queue.  For example instead of

```
self.item = [None] * 4
```

you could use

```
self.item = item
```

then when you create the Node object you can use something like:

```
mycircularqueue = CircularQueue()
mycircularqueue.enqueue('cat')
mycircularqueue.enqueue('dog')
mycircularqueue.enqueue('mouse')
```

to add three items to your queue.

Comment: The reason I used 4 was to make a fixed size. How do I make the tail point back to the head once it reaches size 4? That was the point of self.tail = (self.tail + 1) % 4. Also, I am able to create a queue, but I cannot make it point to the head when it is "full".

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make the tail reach to the head.e.g.

```
list = [1,2,3]
list = list + list[0:1]
```

You'll get:

```
[1,2,3,1]
```

Maybe this is the easy way.